# JSTL & Spring: Accessing methods with arguments

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have an object with a method

```
  public boolean hasPermission(String role) {
   return permissions.contains(role);
  }
```

I want to do the equivalent of:

```
<c:if test="${row.hasPermission(role)}">
    <td></td>
</c:if>
```

But I cannot access the hasPermission method from within the JSP file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of EL (in tomcat 7 for ex.) supports this (`${obj.method(arg)}`)

If you have an older version you have two options:

- Make a custom JSTL function
- Use [JBoss EL extension](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/elenhancements.html)

Comment: You can also declare getter (something like _getPermissions_) and use it from jstl: _row.permissions_

Comment: How would I check that row.permissions contains a certain value?

Comment: @Steve If _row.permissions_ returns Map, you can access it as any other map in jstl (_row.permissions[role]_ IIRC). Same with Set. (Not sure if you can pass parameter into getter directly, but may be worth a try too.)

Comment: you're better off writing a custom jstl function - its very easy to write one, and you'd get rid of this iterate and compare business (which is definitely not a good idea) - see http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html