# How to call java methods in EL?

Tags: java, jsp, el

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSTL & Spring: Accessing methods with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811833/jstl-spring-accessing-methods-with-arguments)

I am trying to access a method using EL like this

```
<jsp:useBean id="search" class="com.app.pro.Search" />
<c:set var="searchResult" value="${search.doSearch(arg0, arg1, arg2)}" />
<c:out value="searchresult = ${searchResult.value}"/>
```

Search.java

```
public SearchResult doSearch(arg0, arg1, arg2){}
```

SearchResult.java

```
public String value;
//getters and setters
```

After deploying i am getting the error

> The function doSearch must be used with a prefix when a default
>   namespace is not specified

How to access this method?

Comment: did you check the possible duplicate?

Comment: How to check duplicates?

Comment: The first comment is a link to it

Comment: EL 6.0 doesn't exist. You're probably talking about Tomcat 6.0. That's a Servlet 2.5 container. Your comment about "servlet-api-2.4" is by the way scary, this suggests that you've dropped a JAR file with that name in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`...